# NullPointerException in

Tags: android

Since I started targetting android M I'm getting NPE in View.getHardwareLayer on many different machines. Two such errors here:

```
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
 raw
android.view.View.getHardwareLayer (View.java:10178)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2863)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10415)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2850)
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild (DrawerLayout.java:1229)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10415)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2850)
com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.drawChild (SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:888)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:10981)
com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.draw (SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:941)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10417)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2850)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:10981)
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw (FrameLayout.java:450)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10417)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2850)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10415)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2850)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10415)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2850)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10415)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2850)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10415)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2850)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:10981)
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw (FrameLayout.java:450)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw (PhoneWindow.java:2126)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10417)
android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw (HardwareRenderer.java:899)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage (ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:4456)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

And another one:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
 raw
android.view.View.getHardwareLayer (View.java:10178)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:2863)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:2489)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10415)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:2597)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10380)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:2597)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10380)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:2597)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10380)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:2597)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10380)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:2597)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10380)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:2597)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10380)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:2597)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10380)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:2597)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:10380)
android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw (HardwareRenderer.java:899)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage (ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:4456)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Is there any change in M that I should be aware of to get rid of these exceptions?

Comment: We don't see any code how shall we help you?

Comment: Oh, you do see. The code is "dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)" for both exceptions.

Comment: But where is the **JAVA CODE**?

Comment: Yes, 40 fragments, 3 activities, 23 adapters, all inflating their own views! If you can guess from the above exception which piece of code is the offender, I can post it.

Comment: If it's crashing on`NativeStart.java`and when you click it gives you the lane that is crashing you should post your `NativeStart.java class`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my NativeStart.java, but a NativeStart.java of HTC Explorer X, Sony LT18I and Megafon SPAI.

Answer (score 4):

OK, it appears it was a Support Library bug. As [stated by Google](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions):

> Fixed crash issues for the `Fragment` class by limiting the use of
>   hardware layers to Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher. ([Issue
>   183896](http://b.android.com/183896))

Thank you, GOOOGLE!!!...